# Random Time & Date increment with Excel or php

Tags: php, excel, notepad++

i want to increase time and date by between 8 & 12 minutes randomly .
Example:

```
Start time : 2018-06-25 19:00:10
      Next : 2018-06-25 19:09:36
      Next : 2018-06-25 19:20:12
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...  : 2018-06-26 11:35:45

and More Like This.
```

if possible i need all time and dates in on Column .

and i already know how to increase time and date with fixed number for example 9 minutes.

How can i do this

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you asking for help with - your tags are conflicting. What have you already tried - post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in b2,

```
=b1+time(0, randbetween(8, 12), 0)
'alternate
=b1+time(0, randbetween(8, 11), randbetween(0, 60))
```